# How to efficiently build a large sparse matrix and overloading a compiled function?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, compile, sparse-arrays, function-compile

I would like to construct a large sparse matrix folding from rank-4 tensor given by the following:

$\mathcal{L}_{1L}^{00}(i,j)=\mathcal{L}_{1L}^{00}(m_1,m_2;M_1,M_2)$

The indices of matrix $(i,j)$ are mapped from $(m_1,m_2;M_1,M_2)$

by $i=N_s(m_1-1)+m_2$ and $j=N_s(M_1-1)+M_2$.

The tensor elements are given by

$\mathcal{L}_{1L}^{00}(m_1,m_2;M_1,M_2)=i \delta_{M_1,m_1}\sum_{\nu=0}^{Ns-1}\xi_{1}(M_2,v)V_d(M_2,v)V_d(v,m_2)-i\delta_{M_2,m_2}\sum_{v=0}^{Ns-1}\xi_{1}^*(M_1,v)V_d(m_1,v)V_d(v,M_1)$

where the function $\xi_1(m,v;V)=i\frac{\beta_2^2}{2\beta_1^2}\left(e^{\frac{E_{v}-E_m-V/2}{kT}}+1\right)^{-1}\sqrt{4\beta^2_1-(E_{v}-E_m-V/2)^2}$

and matrix elements $V_d(m,v)=\langle m|v\rangle=e^{-\lambda^2/2\Omega^2}\sum_{i=0}^{\nu}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\delta_{m-j,\nu-i}(-1)^j\left(\frac{\lambda}{\Omega}\right)^{i+j}\frac{1}{i!j!}\sqrt{\frac{m!\nu!}{(m-j)!(v-i)!}}$

I have already compiled the function $\xi_1$. However, I don't know if I can overload the function such that it can deal with array input and perform the array dot product efficiently in the summation of $v$ ($\sum_{v=0}^{Ns-1}\xi_{1}^*(M_1,v)V_d(m_1,v)V_d(v,M_1)$
) instead of using Table, which is very slow.

Is there any potential improvement I can make here (such as using sparse matrix ... etc).

My code is below, which takes 2 seconds for me to finish. However, if $N_s$ is getting larger, it will be very slow in matrix construction. So I am looking forward to any improvement of it. Many thanks.

> ```
> Clear["Global`*"]
> Ns = 11; (*number of basis*)
> V = 1.84;
> \[Lambda] = 0.3;
> \[CapitalOmega] = 0.5;
> \[Epsilon]0 = 0.5;
> \[Beta]1 = 1; \[Beta]2 = 0.05; kT = 0.0259/300*10; (*10K*)
> (*Franck-Condon factors*)
>
> FK = E^(-\[Lambda]^2/(2 \[CapitalOmega]^2)) Table[\!\(
> \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(\[Nu]\)]\(
> \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
>        0\), \(m\)]\((KroneckerDelta[m - j, \[Nu] - i])\) 
> \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(j\)] 
> \*SuperscriptBox[\((
> \*FractionBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(\[CapitalOmega]\)])\), \(i + j\)] 
> \*FractionBox[\(1.\), \(\(i!\) \(j!\)\)] 
> \*SqrtBox[
> FractionBox[\(\(m!\) \(\[Nu]!\)\), \(\(\((m - j)\)!\) \(\((\[Nu] - 
>             i)\)!\)\)]]\)\), {m, 0, Ns - 1}, {\[Nu], 0, Ns - 1}];
> (*Eigenenergies of oscillator*)
> Em = Table[\[CapitalOmega] (m + 1/2), {m, 0, Ns}];
> (*Eigenenergies of shifted oscillator*)
> E\[Nu] = Table[\[CapitalOmega] (\[Nu] + 1/
>        2) + \[Epsilon]0 - \[Lambda]^2/\[CapitalOmega], {\[Nu], 0, Ns}];
> (*Define elementary functions*)
> cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
>    If[x < -300., 1., If[x > 300., 0., 1./(1. + Exp[x])]], 
>    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
>    Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
> c\[CapitalGamma]0 = 
>   Compile[{{E, _Real}, {qV, _Real}, {\[Beta]1, _Real}, {\[Beta]2, \
> _Real}}, If[
>     Abs[E - qV/2.] <= 
>      2 \[Beta]1, \[Beta]2^2/\[Beta]1^2 Sqrt[
>       4 \[Beta]1^2 - (E - qV/2.)^2], 0.], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
>    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
>    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
> \[Xi]1L[E_, V_] := 
>   I/2 cf[(E - V/2)/kT] c\[CapitalGamma]0[E, V, \[Beta]1, \[Beta]2];
> timing0 = AbsoluteTime[];
> (*Indices are mapped according to (i,j)=(Ns(Subscript[m, \
> 1]-1)+Subscript[m, 2],Ns(Subscript[M, 1]-1)+Subscript[M, 2]) => \
> Subscript[m, 1]=Floor[i/Ns]+1 and Subscript[m, 2]=i (Mod Ns)+1 => \
> Subscript[M, 1]=Floor[j/Ns]+1 and Subscript[M, 2]=j (Mod Ns)+1*)
> L001L = Table[
>    Block[{m1 = Floor[i/Ns] + 1, m2 = Mod[i, Ns] + 1, 
>      M1 = Floor[j/Ns] + 1, M2 = Mod[j, Ns] + 1, \[Xi], \[Xi]a},
>     
>     \[Xi] = 
>      Table[\[Xi]1L[E\[Nu][[i + 1]] - Em[[M2]], V], {i, 0, Ns - 1}];
>     \[Xi]a = 
>      Table[Conjugate[\[Xi]1L[E\[Nu][[i + 1]] - Em[[M1]], V]], {i, 0, 
>        Ns - 1}];
>     I KroneckerDelta[M1, m1] \[Xi].(FK[[M2, All]] FK[[m2, All]]) - 
>      I KroneckerDelta[M2, m2] \[Xi]a.(FK[[M1, All]] FK[[m1, All]])],
>    {i, 0, Ns^2 - 1},
>    {j, 0, Ns^2 - 1}];
> timing1 = AbsoluteTime[];
> Tc = timing1 - timing0;
>
> Print["Tensor \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(L\), \(1  L\), \(00\)]\) \
> constructed in " <> ToString[Tc] <> " seconds."]
> L001L // ArrayPlot
> ```

As you can see, the matrix is very sparse.
[image]

Comment: These index transformations `m1 = Floor[i/Ns] + 1, m2 = Mod[i, Ns] + 1, 
     M1 = Floor[j/Ns] + 1, M2 = Mod[j, Ns] + 1` can indeed be very slow. I would do the opposite: first construct the rank-4 tensor by looping over `m1, m2, M1, M2` and subsequently use `ArrayFlatten` to construct the matrix.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks for the comment. But I think the main bottleneck is on the the $\xi$ function and summation over products, since it's $\mathcal{O}(N_s^3)$.

Comment: I agree with @yarchik. Further, before you try compiling functions, try list-processing i.e. making your functions [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) or simply feeding lists into arithmetic functions so that they can operate on entire lists at once.

Comment: Furthermore, I noticed that $\xi$ should be a matrix according to you formulas. However, you construct it row-by-row. It is not very efficient. Better to construct the whole matrix and then do matrix multiplication.

Comment: @yarchik Yes, you're right. The $\xi$ matrix should be built in the very beginning. But for the arrayFlatten stuff, it's not clear how to fold it in a correct manner.

Comment: @BobLin You said it is not clear how to fold in a correct manner. I do not know what do you plan to do with the matrix, but if you only need to find the eigenvalues, the order does not matter.

Comment: Thanks, actually I figured out how to fold it by testing in small dimensions. The bottleneck is in function xi and not using the KroneckerDelta function but constructing nonzero element by DiagonalMatrix in the beginning.